# How can I concatenate two very different mp3 files(diff bitrate, channels, samplerate, bitdeph)?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

As input I get one mp3 file(input.mp3), then I need to split it into two separate parts(done that) and insert between those parts another mp3(second.mp3).

The problem:
I tried using every single command for concatenating files, converting them to .ts etc etc.
But I always get only the sound of the first mp3 file and the sound of the second is lost. I guess I have to transform my mp3 file into the exact same format as the input.mp3(bitrates, sample rates number of channels) file before I can concatenate it to it.

I could concatenate the two parts of the input.mp3, but no matter what I do I cannot concatenate with second.mp3.

I am using php with exec and ffmpeg.exe file. Is it possible to code it so no matter the input, I can transform second.mp3 into suitable for concatenating mp3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [atrim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim), [asetpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts), and [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i second.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]atrim=end=10,asetpts=N/SR/TB[begin];[0:a]atrim=start=10,asetpts=N/SR/TB[end];[begin][1:a][end]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a]" -map "[a]" output
```

Note: All corresponding streams must have the same parameters in all segments; the filtering system will automatically select a common sample format, sample rate, and channel layout for audio streams. These common parameters will vary depending on the input parameters, so add the [aformat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aformat) filter (or equivalent) if you want consistent results:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i second.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]atrim=end=10,aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,asetpts=N/SR/TB[begin];[1:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[middle];[0:a]atrim=start=10,aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,asetpts=N/SR/TB[end];[begin][middle][end]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a]" -map "[a]" output
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the first command actually did work, could it be said that the quality of output.mp3 will always be the same as the quality of input.mp3, keeping every parameter that matters of input.mp3? I am kind of noob with audio editing <3

Comment: @lukistar No. The input bitrate doesn't really matter because the decoder will fully decode the audio into raw PCM audio, then it will be run through the `-filter_complex`, then encoded. The quality can't be the same anyway because MP3 is lossy. Just listen to it: if it sounds good enough you can use the defaults without doing anything extra. If it doesn't sound good enough provide a higher bitrate see [FFmpeg Wiki: MP3](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3).

Comment: Hey, sorry to ask you a bit of a different question, but now I have to do similar thing to what your command did - but instead of cutting the first audio I need to overlay the second audio at position of the first audio so at that position the first and the second audio plays at the same time... but again using the parameters of the first audio.. something like giving seconds in witch the second audio star playing alongside with the first, hearing both of them..

Comment: @lukistar This site encourages users to should ask one separate question per post, so that should be a new question.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I concatenate two very different mp3 files(diff bitrate, channels, samplerate, bitdeph)?

Let's start with each component...

> bitrate

This one doesn't matter.  MP3 streams can (and do!) change bitrate mid-stream.  As long as you join on a frame header, you're fine.

> bitdepth

The concept of sample bit depth doesn't exist within MP3.  You can capture at 24-bit, encode to MP3, and the decoder will decode to 16-bit.  (Or, with some command line switches, vice versa!)  It's not a problem because bit depth doesn't apply.

> sample rates

This is usually a problem.  Most players don't assume they're going to change output sample rate mid-stream.  Most players don't attempt to resample to stick to the rate they were already outputting at.  I'm not surprised that you'd have some trouble with a changing sample rate.

> channels

This is similar to the sample rate problem in that it requires changing the configuration of the output device.  Even if the player supports it, it isn't going to be seamless.  (Unless you were going from stereo to mono, where the mono could be easily upmixed to stereo.)

> As input I get one mp3 file(input.mp3), then I need to split it into two separate parts(done that) and insert between those parts another mp3(second.mp3).

This actually presents another problem you haven't asked about... timing.  MP3 works in relatively large frames (typically 576 samples), which becomes the resolution at which you can splice.  Not good.  Also, the starts of tracks often have a frame or two of initialization.

A third issue is the bit reservoir.  This is where content from one frame is stored in a different frame that might have extra space.

At the end of the day, you're going to have to decode everything to regular PCM samples, do your splicing, and re-encode to MP3.  You'll also have to re-sample everything to a common clock rate, and mix to a particular channel count.  Fortunately, once decoded to PCM, this is all trivial and standard.  Once your input streams are compatible, you an arbitrarily splice on a PCM frame which is the most granular possible.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Now, I think I understand better what I am trying to do <33

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **concatenate** or merge **different bit rate** and **Mono** and **Stereo** mp3 files into one mp3 file use **`ffmpeg libmp3lame`** library.

Command :

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:'url1.mp3'|'mono_url2.mp3'|'stereo_url3.mp3'" -c:a libmp3lame output_file.mp3
```

Comment: this is working